# XSockets.net client can not subscribe to events

Tags: mono, xsockets.net

I am using xsockets server version 2.6.1.0 running on mono 3.2.4 and javascript client version 3.0.2 on browser.
Client can publish notifications to server without any problems. But subscriptions are not received.

XSockets controller source:

```
public class ChatController : XSocketController
{
    public void Chat(ITextArgs textArgs)
    {
        //this.Send(textArgs); <-- in this case calling client is notified
        this.SendToAll (textArgs);  // <-- calling this does not notify clients
        var count = EventSubscribers.Count; // count is 0
    }
}
```

Client side:

var conn = new XSockets.WebSocket("ws://localhost:4502/ChatController");

```
$("#Send").click(function(){
    conn.publish('chat', { text:"test message"});   //server receives message
});

conn.subscribe('chat', function(data){
    //This event is not fired when SendToAll on server side is called.
});
```

Any ideas how I can make this stuff work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use 2.6.1.0 with the latest javascript API. Update server to the latest (3.0.4.1) and you will be fine.

Or downgrade the javascript to a older version. Probably something like 2.9...

Comment: Yes, needed JSApi 2.5.3 version. Now it works. Actually I am planning to use client from Unity3d, but can not find .NET 2/3.5 version on nugget. Maybe You have somewhere older .NET client?

Comment: I have a "non public" 2.0 and also 3.5 client some where. I can open source it on github since you need it. Might take a few days though since I have a busy schedule right now. ok?

Comment: @Uffe did you ever open source this?  I am also looking to use xscokets with unity4

Comment: @odyth Not yet published but our users have been getting a preview of a new client lib. We now support .NET 2.0, 3.5, 4.0 and NETMF 4.2. Also Xamarin Android and Xamarin iOS + working on windows phone 8.1.
I have a friend tesing the .NET 2.0 & 3.5 for Unity4 right now